# Dropdown's change handler is working a bit weird

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Here is what I have done:

```
<html><head><script type="text/javascript"> 
function loaded(){
    var selectElems=document.getElementsByName("select");
    for(i=0;i<selectElems.length;i++){
      var elem=selectElems[i];
      elem.onchange=function(){
          alert(elem.selectedIndex);
       }
     }
} </script></head>
<body onload="loaded()">
<select name="select">
      <option>0</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option> </select>
 <select name="select">
      <option>0</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option></select>
 <select name="select">
      <option>0</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option></select>
</body></html>
```

I need to get selected index of element with JavaScript. But I had a problem with that.
Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/aRMpt/139/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `elem` always points to the last `select` element. The simplest solution is to use `this` in the handler instead of the elem variable http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/aRMpt/140/

```
function loaded(){
    var selectElems=document.getElementsByName("select");
    for(i=0;i<selectElems.length;i++){
      var elem=selectElems[i];
      elem.onchange=function(){
          // This points to the select element that was changed
          alert(this.selectedIndex);
       }
     }
}
```

This doesn't really tell you what your problem is though. It's a workaround (though a good one). The reason your code doesn't work is because your closure function `onchange` uses the same `elem` from the closure. By the time your `onchange` is called, `elem` points to the last `select` element. A way to avoid this is to introduce another closure that *freezes* the elem for your onchange handler http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/aRMpt/142/

```
function loaded(){
    var selectElems=document.getElementsByName("select");
    for(i=0;i<selectElems.length;i++){
      var elem=selectElems[i];
      // Freeze the elem variable by creating a function that passes
      // the elem and creates a separate closure for each handler
      elem.onchange= (function(el) {
          // This is the function that will actually be the handler
          return function(){
             // This points to the select element that was changed
             alert(el.selectedIndex);
          }
     }) (elem) 
}
```

Here's another example that may help you understand how the above example works.

```
// This is a function that returns another function
// Its only reason is so that we don't use the shared closure 
// variables from the outer scope, it freezes the el
// variable at the moment its called and so that it's available
// when the handler is called
function createOnChangeHandler(el) {
  return function() {
     alert(el.selectedIndex);
  }
}

function loaded(){
    var selectElems=document.getElementsByName("select");
    for(i=0;i<selectElems.length;i++){
      var elem=selectElems[i];
      // If we just use elem here, its value will be what it was assigned last
      // in the loop. That is because the handler won't be called until
      // this loop has finished. However, by calling another function, 
      // a new scope is created with the value that we're passing into it
      elem.onchange = createOnChangeHandler(elem);
}
```

This freezing of variables could also be accomplished by using [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), but this only works in newer browsers; however, the above link shows you how to make it work for browsers that don't support it. http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/aRMpt/143/

```
function loaded(){
    var selectElems=document.getElementsByName("select");
    for(i=0;i<selectElems.length;i++){
      var elem = selectElems[i];
      elem.onchange = (function (el) {
        alert("Select index: " + el.selectedIndex)
      }).bind(null, el);
}
```

Comment: I think every JS developer has run across this problem before. I would make sure you understand the second solution since you may need it in the future (say if you wanted to use the `i` variable). But for this case, I would just use the first one.

Comment: To be honest, I'm newbie to javascript, especially your second example is a little difficult to understand, and now I'm googling around.... if you know any good tutorial about this example can you point me

Comment: Added some comments about how it works. Feel free to ask questions, and don't worry, it does take some time to digest, but you can't really call yourself a good JS developer until you understand it.

Comment: @JamshidAsatillayev This is not a great article, some of the examples are weird, but it does explain it. http://www.javascriptkata.com/2007/04/11/a-common-problem-with-the-powerful-javascript-closures/